# Accessibility analysis of an element

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm doing an accessibility analysis of a website using the Accessibility Insights for Web extension.

In point 7.1 it is requested:

*If an anchor element functions as a custom widget, it must have the appropriate ARIA widget role.
For this requirement, Accessibility Insights for Web highlights anchor elements that are possible to custom widgets. These elements don't have an ARIA widget role, but they do have some custom widget markup, such as tabindex="-1", an ARIA attribute, a non-widget role, or no href.
Note: If no matching/failing instances are found, this requirement will automatically be marked as pass.
In the target page, examine each highlighted anchor element to verify that it functions as a link (i.e., it navigates to new content in the current page or in a new page).
Record your results:
Select Fail for any instances that do not meet the requirement.
Otherwise, select Pass. Or, after you have marked all failures, select Pass unmarked instances.*

And some buttons are highlighted, which have this structure:

```
<a data-toggle="tab" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;cursor:pointer">Test button</a>
```

Or this:

```
<a href="/Presences/Index" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="300" data-close-others="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar bg-color-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <span>Presences</span>
</a>
```

I don't understand what the problem is, and if actually there is a problem in these elements. I tried adding `role="button"` but it didn't work. Adding a description via an `aria` attribute didn't work either.
Can you help me please?

Comment: The first anchor is flagged because it has no `href` and is uaed out of scope. An anchor is an element to redirect to another resource such as another website. Without `href` or readable target for screen readers it is considered a button and needs the information that it works as a button instead.

Comment: It’s not even considered a button, to be precise. The default role for `<a>` is `generic`. Additionally, it lacks a tab stop, so it’s usable with a screen reader at all. Adding `href="#"` would solve it, but the library needs to support that by aborting the event.

Answer (score 0):

The role should probably be `tab`, which needs to be inside a `tablist`, have a `tabpanel` somewhere, its `aria-expanded` state needs to be managed, and it needs to be keyboard focusable, f.e. by using `tabindex="0"`.

The [role of an `<a>` without `href` is `generic`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-a-no-href). It does not make sense that it’s an `<a>`, since without `href` user agents (browsers) don’t provide a tab stop or keyboard listeners either.

As you can see, it’s not easily fixed by adding a role.

If you chose an inaccessible library to implement these tabs, it is not realistic to fix its issues from the outside. In my opinion, your choices are to

- Choose another library that has better accessibility
- Contribute to the library by raising the accessibility issues you encounter, and ideally fix them and send pull requests

You can read the Tabs pattern from the [ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabs/) to see what needs to be done.

Comment: The second snippet I pasted belongs to this menu: https://ibb.co/F53DjZn
Some buttons in this menu are just links to other pages, other buttons are dropdown menus. Do you think it's better to use tabs to enclose the whole menu?

Comment: Oh I see. That changes the roles you should use. Have a look at [Menu and Menubar Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menubar/), it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Zeld or is it?